# How do I search for text on a given Trello board?

Tags: trello

For example, I wanted to check the [Trello for Trello](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c) list to see if a feature request was already registered.  When I search, it doesn't limit the search to the current board, making the search results considerably less than useful.  Is there a way to limit the search to the current board?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now limit your search to a specific board by starting your search with "board:xxx". xxx can be the board id or part of the title.  For example I have a board called "Current Development ".  To find the string 'searchval' on it I use:

```
board:current searchval
```

Comment: I use "board:current xxx", and I get no results.

Comment: this works because you have "current" in the name of your board. It's not generic to always search for the board you're viewing.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, you can't, but search will be improving soon. We'll update here when you can do this.

Comment: Any updates on this? The search still feels not very functional a.t.m. Is there a feature request I can vote on and follow?

Comment: +1 on this! Also it'd be great to have a checkbox option to not search archived cards for a given search.

Comment: We've just released a big search improvement. Closing this question.

Comment: Can you answer the question on how limit searches with the new Search Features? I still can't find what I need.